# What are some common FOV for third person games?

Tags: camera, third-person-view

I am trying to decide on a field of view (FOV) for a third person game and I really don't know where to start. It would be very helpful to have some points of reference from recent TPS games and the FOV they use by default. The trouble is many third person games (or at least those I have tried) do not have any settings or information about what their default FOV is. I have had a look at Uncharted 4, Hitman (2016), The Division and GTA 5 but cannot find information about their FOV anywhere.

I understand that each game is different and the type of gameplay will determine the FOV choice here, but it would be very useful for me to have some existing examples as a starting point. Is there any good place to find this out?

Comment: There is nothing such as "good  FOV", you need to decide yourself what feels the best. A higher FOV can show more, but makes everything appear ad if they are farther, a smaller one makes everything seem closer but it shows less

Comment: The distortions are inevitable, you esentially convert a slightly round area to flat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to use 75, 80, 115 and 125 degrees horizontally, for 1, 2, 3 and 4 (lined up) monitors respectively; rendering large outdoor scene. It's user-configurable (.ini file) and requires a re-start if changing. This solution/selection is only one of many possible.

It depends on your scene. Make it look good!

A too wide FOV causes restless movement and erratic sizes at left & right outer edges and stretches the center area inwards the screen in an innatural way. Otoh, if a racing game, that gives an good impression of fast movement.

A too narrow FOV gives a binocular effect, where a small mouse movement/camera direction change causes the scene to be restless and hard to control.

You can solve from this:

```
tan(fovY / 2) = tan(fovX / 2) / aspectratio
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it! It takes a bit of digging, but this website shows the default FOV settings for many games, including third person ones: http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Category:Games

This is what I was looking for as a point of reference.